# Finding the resolution of the discrete Fourier transform of an image

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Suppose I have a 2d function defined on a square of length $L$, that is given as an $N \times N$ matrix of values.

The resolution to which we know the function is $\delta L = L/N$.  We may take the (discrete) Fourier transform of the image, which will return an $N \times N$ matrix of complex values.

My question is, what is the resolution $\delta k$ of the Fourier transformed matrix in terms of $N$ and $L$?